# Not all docVariable fields updating

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In Word 2010 have created a userform for a document at work, allowing for information to be entered that is then input into the document repeatedly throughout. I'm using docVariable fields to achieve this.

My problem is that one of the docVariable fields won't populate. The allocated space simply sits blank. If I right-click where I know the field to be and select "edit field" the dialogue box I receive seems to know what docVariable field exists, and when I press OK the field is replicated and the value entered now shows.

Can someone please suggest how I can overcome this issue.

Comment: 1. How are you updating all the fields? (NB, going into Print Preview does not necessarily update *all* fields, despite what people sometimes say). (2) Can you use Alt-F9 to show the field coding for the DOCVARIABLE field. It should look something like this: { DOCVARIABLE myvar }, or perhaps { DOCVARIABLE "my var" } if the variable name has spaces in it. Is that what you see? Is the field nested inside any other fields, or does it contain any fields inside it, or is it in an 'unusual' place (e.g. anywhere not in an ordinary paragraph.